# Collapsing values of a Pandas column based on Non-NA value of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like this in a csv file which I am importing to pandas df

[image]

I want to collapse the values of Type column by concatenating its strings to one sentence and keeping it at the first row next to date value while keeping rest all rows and values same.

As shown below.

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ffill` + `transform`

```
df1=df.copy()
df1[['Number', 'Date']]=df1[['Number', 'Date']].ffill()
df1.Type=df1.Type.fillna('')
s=df1.groupby(['Number', 'Date']).Type.transform(' '.join)
df.loc[df.Date.notnull(),'Type']=s
df.loc[df.Date.isnull(),'Type']=''
```

Comment: whats df? is it df1?

Comment: @Baktaawar *I have a data like this in a csv file which I am importing to pandas df*

Comment: Is it possible to group Type variable changes with another column? Like I have another variable "number_in"  which is usually empty except at the end it has a value. I want the value to be right at the top in the same row as data and Number have value. Pls see the edit for screenshot.